# Add two polynomials with iterative method using liked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to add two polynomials with iterative method using linked list but this code is adding just the first element. Where is the mistake and how can I solve it?

```
struct pol{
    int n;
    double c;
    struct pol *urm;};
typedef struct pol * POL;
POL add_pol(POL,POL); 
POL add_pol(POL p, POL q)
{
    POL t;
    POL w;
    for(;p;p=p->urm)
    {
        if(p->n == q->n)
        {
            t=init_term(p->n,p->c+q->c);
            t=insert_term(t,w);
        }
        if(p->n > q->n)
            t= insert_term (p,q);
        if(q->n > p->n)
            t= insert_term (q,p);
    return t;
    }
}
POL init_term(int n, double c)
{
    POL w;
    w=(POL)malloc(sizeof(struct pol));
    w->n = n;
    w->c = c;
    return w;
}
POL insert_term(POL p, POL q)
{
    POL w;
    w=init_term(p->n,p->c);
    w->urm=add_pol(p->urm,q);
    return w;
}
```

Comment: Now is probably a great time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you, for example, step through your code line by line in a debugger the problem should become very obvious.

Comment: your `return t;` is supposed to be OUTSIDE the for loop

Comment: The result is an infinite loop if I put return outside the loop

Comment: @joey then you have a cyclic linked list

Comment: And how can I "repare" it?

Comment: `w` is not defined when `t=insert_term(t,w);` is called.  Post a [MCVE].

Comment: I defined w with NULL  but the loop still there.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize urm.

```
POLINOM init_term(int n, double c)
{
    POLINOM w;
    w=(POL)malloc(sizeof(struct pol));
    w->n = n;
    w->c = c;
    w->urm = NULL;
    return w;
}
```

Then move then return outside the loop.

Comment: Still got problems....the same loop